# Change value from top to bottom conditionally on columns in a Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, shift

How do I copy the previous value from top to bottom conditionally on columns in a Python Pandas dataframe?
How can i solve it by vectorization with Pandas?
I created columns B and C by operating on a dataframe.
I want to change the columns in the dataframe from top to bottom.

I have this

```
list_one = [1.10, 1.20, 1.25, 1.30, 0.50, 0.60, 1.70, 1.80, 2.00]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list_one})
df['B'] = df['A'] + df['A'] * 0.1
df['C'] = df['A'] - df['A'] * 0.1
print (df)

output>>>
    A       B       C
0   1.100   1.210   0.990
1   1.200   1.320   1.080
2   1.250   1.375   1.125
3   1.300   1.430   1.170
4   0.500   0.550   0.450
5   0.600   0.660   0.540
6   1.700   1.870   1.530
7   1.800   1.980   1.620
8   2.000   2.200   1.800
```

**To be more descriptive, I need this conditions and dataframe.**

```
if A < B and A > C :
    B = B.shift()
    C = C.shift()
    D = 0
elif A > B:
    D = 1
elif A < B:
    D = -1

How can i this output>>>
    A        B       C      D
0   1.100   1.210   0.990   0
1   1.200   1.210   0.990   0
2   1.250   1.375   1.125   1
3   1.300   1.375   1.125   0
4   0.500   0.550   0.450   -1
5   0.600   0.660   0.540   1
6   1.700   1.870   1.530   1
7   1.800   1.870   1.530   0
8   2.000   2.200   1.800   1
```

**My faulty code is not giving the above output**

```py
    # Conditions zero <br/>
    biger_C   = df2["A"] > df2["C"].shift(1)
    smaller_B  = df2["A"] < df2["B"].shift(1)
    
    # Conditions smaller or bigger
    bigger_B   = df2["A"] > df2["B"].shift(1)
    smaller_C = df2["A"] < df2["C"].shift(1)
    
    df2.loc[smaller_B & biger_C , "B"] = df2["B"].shift()
    df2.loc[smaller_B & biger_C , "C"] = df2["C"].shift()
    df2.loc[bigger_B , "D"] = 1
    df2.loc[smaller_C , "D"] = -1
```

Comment: The expected output doesn't match the pseudocode. For example in row 2, A < B (1.25 < 1.375), and A > C, yet D is set to 1.

Comment: @butterflyknife you are right, how can i achieve the result i want?

Comment: If your pseudocode is not right, I don't know how you expect to achieve your desired results, so I can't help. Please fix your pseudocode with a correct description of your algorithm.

Comment: @butterflyknife I edit my question. Please look to below the pseudo code output. I need "How can i this output>>>" result. And I added my conditions and df changer codes at the end of the post.